# Correct directory for downloadable content

Tags: ios

After my app was rejected by Apple today for not following the iOS Data Storage guidelines I'm a bit confused about which directory I should actually use.

The app is a fairly basic newsreading that stores thumbnails and pdf's on the user's device, before all of this was stored inside `NSDocumentDirectory`. But now I'm wondering if I should store all this data inside `NSCachesDirectory` or `/tmp`

I've heard that the `NSCachesDirectory` gets cleared when updating the app, I would rather have this not happen so the user doesn't have to download everything again.

Answer (score 0):

In the NSCachesDirectory.

It isn't deleted upon update. I can tell you that from personal experience.  I stored a ton of resources nested in that directory structure including plists, images and PDFs.